# Checkbox tree with Buttons in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm, checkboxtree

I have a specific requirement to add a Checkbox tree having Action buttons on each node.
 As I am new to Reactjs, I tried certain options like react-sortable-tree and react-checkbox-tree, which solves either Action Button or Checkbox requirement.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sortable-tree
Could I get help to find necessary control or control behaviour to fulfil the requirement acceptance?

Thank you,
Sagar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [rc-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-tree) which is used by [Ant Design](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce) it has checkable property which makes each tree node a checkbox. 
If it does not solve your problem you can create a custom tree view yourself. There are plenty of examples on web ([How TO - Tree View](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_treeview.asp)).

Comment: Thanks for sharing, the rc-tree information. Below, style could resolve my issue for now.
http://react-component.github.io/tree/examples/basic.html